# Screen lock customization for android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Customizing Android Lock Screen functionality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948617/customizing-android-lock-screen-functionality)

I'm planning to explore the possibilities on how to make a screen lock better (like pattern based). It will be great help if someone points out the difficulty level or where to actually start digging. This is going to be my project idea for minor research paper. What do u guys think or if anyone has more ideas worth exploring, I would like to consider it.
reagrds

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the screen lock application is not supported by the current Android SDK. Hopefully, they will provide options for this in the future. Sorry!

Comment: Thanks.. But it is possible to realize my idea by making necessary changes in the original source code of android wrt screen lock and compile+build again...wat do u say.. shall I ask on android Google groups

Comment: Oh, if you are willing to modify the firmware, you can do whatever you want. The android-porting Google Group would be a good place to ask questions.