# Customizing Android Lock Screen functionality?

Tags: android, customizing, lockscreen

I will like to develop an App which modifies LockScreen of Android. I have read in some forums that it is not supported as yet in the SDK but there are some applications available that does exactly that.

One can surf [Screen Suite Lock Screen](http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/tools/screen-suite-lockscreen-trial_fznq.html?nav=related)

Can someone let me know is it actually possible to customize LockScreen and implement our own way of Lock Screen?

Regards

Sunil

Comment: possible duplicate of [Screen lock customization for android ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758006/screen-lock-customization-for-android)

Comment: Its not a duplicate. That post was posted by someone else. I just wanted to know how the application mentioned above does the same thing. If you know the answer then please let me know.

Comment: This might help you: http://sites.google.com/site/paranoidandroidproject/

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have views displayed above the lock screen and to make it dismiss the lock screen.
It's a dirty solution, but the only one as long as there is no api to replace the lock screen.

[Android activity over default lock screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629179/android-activity-over-default-lock-screen)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED

Comment: You can use the [Adenda SDK](http://adendamedia/com). It essentially extends the standard Android libraries