# Android activity over default lock screen

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, lockscreen, android-windowmanager

How can I display an `Activity` or `Dialog` to be visible over the lock screen?

I have already tried displaying my lock activity when screen turns on by setting various window type in `Activity.onCreate()` method:

`TYPE_PRIORITY_PHONE`
`TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT`
`TYPE_KEYGUARD`

and others together with `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` and `INTERNAL_SYSTEM_WINDOW` permissions.

My activity is visible after I unlock the device.

UPDATE:

I actually already managed to display my own Activity instead of default lock screen. It work perfectly unless you use HOME button.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to implement your own lock screen or you want your alert window to be shown over lock screen (whatever is is) or ... ?

Comment: Actually I wish I was able to implement both: own lock screen and a dialog over existing lock screen.

Comment: I can tell you about showing a window over lock screen: see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED

Comment: Thanks. However it is for API level 5 and higher. I am deleoping an app for API level 4.

Comment: Would you be able to post that code?

Comment: @plugmind: I ran into same issue,can you plz share your code for reference ?

Comment: is there any xml setting rather than in code?

Comment: @plugmind, have you achieved the required task,,, I am stucking at the same....

Answer (score 124):

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

try using this flags to disable lock screen when the activity is started.

After API level 17 you can use

```
<activity
        android:name=".yourActivityName"
        android:showOnLockScreen="true"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" >
```

showOnLockScreen like in the example...

Comment: this doesn't even require any permissions. Surprising.

Comment: not working in my case, is any special permission needed for this?

Comment: The thing is that at least on 4.4 this does not work when there is a password set on the lock screen. does anyone know how to keep the lock screen on but still be able to display the dialogue over it?

Comment: Does anyone know how to deny home button in in case of custom activity for lock screen? Home button simply closes the activity and brings to home screen.

Comment: @karate There is Screen Pinning - http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html, but it does not seem to be very easy to use (the app must have Device Owner permissions)

Answer (score 33):

Don't go for activity, because android will not show lock screen behind your activity for security reason, so use service instead of Activity.

Below is my code in onStartCommand of my service.

```
WindowManager mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

View mView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.score, null);

WindowManager.LayoutParams mLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0, 0,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
/* | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON */,
PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);

mWindowManager.addView(mView, mLayoutParams);
```

And add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />` to manifest

Comment: I could use this to show the layout on top of the display. But it is not receiving events, even if I add event handlers. How to overcome that problem?

Comment: @nagylzs it will not receive events, because it's a compromise to be able to show your apps screen(which is not a system app) on lock screen. It's security issue. Generally Android didn't allow you to show your screen on lock screen having touch events,(e.g.  you can steal some ones passwords by showing a transparent screen on lock screen)

Comment: did you try using TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR so that you can receive events?

Comment: The layout over lockscreen is not **showing in full screen** that is not covering the whole mobile screen.what to do for covering the **whole mobile screen**

Comment: layout.score not found please help.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "android will not show lock screen behind your activity for security reason" given that other answers show how to use an activity and it works just fine?  What is the benefit of this approach compared to the others?

Answer (score 19):

Use this in onCreate method

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);  
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON); 
// This line should be before setContentView..      
setContentView(......);
```

Hope this will work
Thanks

Comment: @Subha, did you get any solution  to avoid display while phone ringing. alarm ringing ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use code in any of answers here that you think it's working. Then to prevent *HOME* button to work, change `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` or `TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY` (depends on what you currently use) to `TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR`:

```
params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD,
    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
);
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
mOverlay = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, (ViewGroup) null);
mWindowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
mWindowManager.addView(mOverlay, params);
```