# run my activity before screen lock activity at phone startup in android

Tags: android-activity

Similar to:
[Android activity over default lock screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629179/android-activity-over-default-lock-screen)

I want to start the activity before the lock screen appeares at phone startup.  I have searched a lot but didn't find a matching post.  Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

See the source code for the Android core DeskClock app here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.1_r2/com/android/deskclock/AlarmAlert.java?av=f

The code you want appears to be the Window.addFlags() call on line 81.