# Start an Activity even when Android phone is in locked mode / on lock screen

Tags: android, android-wake-lock

How I can start my activity even when phone is in locked mode so I can access my application?

I want to ring an alarm first using `ringAlarm()` then goes to another activity that will display `alertdialog` to stop the alarm.

It works fine if phone is active, but when the phone is locked, it just alarms continuously and by the time i unlock the phone, the stop alarm button doesn't activate. Please help me. Thanks for help in advance.

Here is my code:

```
public class EAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static String sender;
public static String sms = "";
public static Ringtone r;
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); 
    Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus"); 
    SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdusObj.length]; 
    for (int i = 0; i<pdusObj.length; i++) 
    { 
            messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu ((byte[]) 
            pdusObj[i]); 
            sender = messages[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            sms = messages[i].getMessageBody();//save sms to string
    } 

    for (SmsMessage msg : messages) {
        if (msg.getMessageBody().contains("alert")) {

            Intent openStopAlarm = new Intent("proj.receiver.STOPALARM");
            openStopAlarm.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            ringAlarm(context);
            context.startActivity(openStopAlarm);
            abortBroadcast();
        }//end if
    }//end for
}// end onreceive

//ring the alarm
public void ringAlarm(Context context)
{
     Uri alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
     if(alert == null){
         // alert is null, using backup
         alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
         if(alert == null){  // 
             // alert backup is null, using 2nd backup
             alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);               
         }
     }
     r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context.getApplicationContext(), alert);
     AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
     int maxVolumeAlarm = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
     int maxVolumeRing = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
     audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
     audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, maxVolumeAlarm,AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
     audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, maxVolumeRing,AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
     r.play();
        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "alarm started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
//end ringAlarm()
}
```

I've seen a code on how to do it but I didn't know how to use it. so I'm still having the same problem. Here's the code.

```
public class DismissLock extends Activity {

PowerManager pm;
WakeLock wl;
KeyguardManager km;
KeyguardLock kl;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i("INFO", "onCreate() in DismissLock");
    pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    km=(KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    kl= km.newKeyguardLock("INFO");
    wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP|PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "INFO");
    wl.acquire(); //wake up the screen
    kl.disableKeyguard();// dismiss the keyguard

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    wl.release(); 
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    wl.acquire();//must call this!
}

}
```

Answer (score 9):

You just need to set a few additional window flags:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
        + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
        + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
        + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

Source: [Android activity over default lock screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629179/android-activity-over-default-lock-screen)

Comment: how do i insert it in my code. because i got an error that's saying that getWindow() is undefined. i'm sorry for a noob question

Comment: You should be able to call it from inside an `Activity`.

Comment: call any class how can i use

Answer (score 2):

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
    + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
    + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
    + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

paste above code in that activity which you want to excute at your lock screen. put  code inside oncreate();