# Are there way start activity over lock screen?

Tags: java, android

I need start activity over lock screen. It can be small activity on lock screen or fully new lock screen. It must start with lock button click

How to do this? I already have activity, broadcast reciver and service to do all job, but don't know how to put activity over lock screen.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629179/android-activity-over-default-lock-screen .check this link

Answer (score 3):

In your Activity's `onCreate()`, before calling `setContentView()`, add this:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
```

For all the window flags you can set, refer to the [`documentation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html)

Comment: can we do the same thing above android M ? any hint ? @A--C

Comment: @Radhey I would assume so, but I have not tried it myself