# Android make app active over custom lockscreen (Go Locker, etc)

Tags: android, lockscreen

I have scoured the Internet for an answer, all with no luck.  I have tried numerous suggestions on this site to make my app display and override the custom lockscreen.  I can dislay my app over the stock lock screens with no problem.  Again, the problem is with any custom lockscreen, Go Locker, Lock Screen 7, etc...

Here is what I have tried w/ no luck.

[Android activity over default lock screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629179/android-activity-over-default-lock-screen)

---

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

---

```
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```

---

```
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```

---

```
final Window win = getWindow();
win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

---

Like I said, I have pretty much tried everything w/ flags.  I do not want to use the deprecated keyguard unlock methods.  Somebody else has to have this same problem?!

Comment: Not a single person has run into this problem???

Comment: did you setgetWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD); or something, cause this may effect the FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED