# Android: Starting here maps over lock screen without need to select route

Tags: navigation

Is there any specific Intent specification available to **start and show the "here WeGo" App over a locked device screen** and automatically start turn by turn routing?

The **Turn-By-Turn navigation should start directly without any user interaction**.

I tried two implementations:

1. Explicit call of here maps:
   `Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("here.directions://v1.0/mylocation/"+lat+","+lng+",Test?ref=<Ref>&m=w");
   Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
   mapIntent.setAction("com.here.maps.DIRECTIONS");
   mapIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
   context.startActivity(mapIntent);`
2. Implicit via "google-maps-intent":

   `Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + lat + "," + lng);
   Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
   context.startActivity(mapIntent);`

With both options I'm able to start hereWeGo from a background service even if device is locked. But the user needs to unlock the device to start navigation by a click.

Google Maps e.g.starts routing directly although the map is not visible over the lock screen.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible given this seems to bypass the user's security model?

Comment: E.g. Android camera does this . According to dev documetation every activity can have the option "android:showOnLockScreen="true" in the manifest. Additionaly with the solution described here: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541150/start-activity-from-lockscreen" you can have every activity on lock screen. You would never give access to private data but starting a navigation with limited access would from my point of view not imply any security issues.