# I am trying to create a notification like one in LINE app. Their notification appear above even screen lock

Tags: android, notifications

I am new to android programming.
I am trying to create a notification like one in LINE app.
Their notification appear above even screen lock.
*How to implement a notification like that.?*
Please help me.

Comment: I tried floating window... Alert window.. But still it doesn't come over screen lock

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629179/android-activity-over-default-lock-screen