# Android FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED when invoking activity from history

Tags: android, android-intent, lockscreen

I've been trying to use FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED and FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD to display an activity each time someone turn the screen on. It works well most of the time but there is some case causing strange behaviour. This happens when the activity is already existing and I send it a intent after it has been moved back in the history stack, by using the <kbd>Home</kbd> button.

First, if I press the <kbd>Home</kbd> button when on my activity, then switch the screen off and on, the activity is expected to be displayed right away as it was. However what is displayed instead is the basic android lockscreen. My activity is behind.

Worst, sometime, if I touch the home screen, then turn the screen off and on, the home screen overlay (all appli logo and widgets) are displayed with my activity in the background!

The intent I am using each time the screen is turned off to laucn and recall the activity :

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

So, it seems that when my activity is in the history stack, it sometimes does not correctly get recalled and bypass the android lockscreen. Is there something wrong with my intent?

Answer (score 0):

Add more flags :

```
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
```

Wither via `Intent.addFlags()` or using `getWindow().addFlags()` from your activity. These flag will disable lockscreen when your activity is started

This will solve your query

Reference Answer : [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5727133/1994950)

Comment: Nope, i cannot turn the screen on. Because my activity is created when the screen is turned off, so that its immediatly ready when the screen is turned on. I am doing some work inside that half a second to be done, and load a webview. So I cannot make my users wait after the screen is turned on for the webpage to load.

Comment: Up : I tried to add those flags, and i doesn't even work. The android lockscreen still show up if my activity is not on top of the history stack

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate the [Adenda](http://adendamedia.com) SDK in your app to achieve what you're after. They let you display what you want on the lock screen relatively easily.

I'm affiliated with Adenda, for full disclosure

Comment: I just want to unsertant why my activity does not correctly show when coming from the history stack. That's the last problem I got with it and I don't want to change everything at this point.