# Activity not opening on Android lock screen

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Whenever I try to open my activity on the lock screen through a pending intent, it automatically closes itself before appearing. Its `onCreate()`, `onStart()`, `onResume()` methods are called, but then suddenly `onStop()` is called automatically. I have set all the required flags to wake up my device and turn the screen on in `onResume()` method. This issue is only with the lock screen. Any suggestions?

This is my `onResume` method:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.i("CallScreen", "onResume()");
    this.getWindow().setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN|
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON|
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN|
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON|
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    handler = new Handler();
    r = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i("CallScreen", "run()");
            startTimer();
            playSound(CallScreen.this, getAlarmUri());
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
}
```

Comment: dude see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629179/android-activity-over-default-lock-screen

Comment: can you show your `onResume()` method?

Comment: the upper one is the best sol there is. when u use the flags mentioned in it then whenever the activity starts the lockscreen will be disabled only if not  password protected..

Comment: I want to know why onStop() is automatically called after onResume() before activity appears?