# How to check Grant Permissions at Run Time when phone is locked?

Tags: android, android-permissions

My app has a runtime permission for location. It works fine in the normal cases. But when the phone is in locked state, the system permission popup/dialog does not come. Is it possible to show the system permissions dialog when the phone is in locked state as well?

Comment: not possible AFAIK

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629179/android-activity-over-default-lock-screen This might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to ask permission when the phone is locked. But you can send a **Notification** to the user to request permission.

On the click of `Notification` open an activity and get a permission from the user.

More info about Notification.https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: Nice approach, sir.