# iOS: App in Locked Screen

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I know from the Maps App in iOS that when I start a route and the phone is locked, it still shows me the route in background. When I want to go back to the App I have to unlock the phone. Is this also possible in Ionic/Cordova?

Example: 
[image]

Comment: Yes, you can at least in android, but you have to use an native android-activity thats shows the same content as your cordova-webview (in your case a map). Therefore you have to use or implement a cordova-plugin that creates an activity like in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5727133/2401386). Then this "show-activity-plugin" combined with this ["lock-screen-listener-plugin"](https://github.com/kitolog/cordova-plugin-screen-locker) you can achieve this. Good Luck!