# How to run Activity with focus when lock screen is active?

Tags: android, lockscreen

Goal is: run Activity to foreground from Service when phone has locked screen, and set window focus in launched Activity.

Prepare:
set phone to the locked state by power button,
run Activity from Service:

```
Intent i = new Intent(mCtx, RecActivity.class);
i.putExtra(RecActivity.INTENT_REQUEST, intentExtra);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
ctx.startActivity(i); //ctx is context
```

In Activity `onCreate()` run this method:

```
private void checkIntentExtraData(){
    try {
        //Check Intent
        Intent i = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
        if(extras != null) {
            /*PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
                    | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
                    | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "INFO");
            wl.acquire();*/

            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD); //This constant was deprecated in API level 26.
                window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED); //This constant was deprecated in API level 27. => setShowWhenLocked(  
            }

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) { //API 26+ Android 8.0+
                KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
                if(km != null)
                    km.requestDismissKeyguard(this, null);
            }

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) { //API 27+ Android 8.1+
                setShowWhenLocked(true);
                setTurnScreenOn(true);
            }

            Log.i(TAG, "hasWindowFocus: "+hasWindowFocus()); //TODO
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Activity is run, callbacks are: `onCreate()`=>`onResume()`=>`onPause()`.
I do not want to run `onPause()` method. It's probably, because Activity has no focus (`hasWindowFocus()` return false).

Any suggestions? Thank you.

I tried too, but not working:

```
android:showOnLockScreen="true"
```

in Manifest.

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629179/android-activity-over-default-lock-screen) may help you

Comment: I read this, but not help.

Answer (score 0):

I think `km.requestDismissKeyguard(this, null);` should be called after the `setShowWhenLocked()` method