# How do I show a Widget over lockscreen in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, lockscreen

I am building a VoIP calling app in Flutter. I need to alert the user and show a Widget on the screen so that the user can accept or reject incomming calls without unlocking the phone. So basically I need a Flutter version for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5727133/1529746).

Comment: Not sure if you can do this without doing a native call using a Flutter Platform Channel

Comment: Showing a notification not enough?

Comment: Actually I need something similar to the WhatsApp calling screen. With a sliding button widget.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use MethodChannel via your flutter app for native android access. In android, you can create  a notification , with setFullScreenIntent(..)
Official documentation mentions , *[Only for use with extremely high-priority notifications demanding the user's immediate attention, such as an incoming phone call](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder#setFullScreenIntent(android.app.PendingIntent,%20boolean))*

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"methodId")
                .setContentText(" content ")
                .setContentTitle("Title..")
                .setFullScreenIntent(...)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.launch_background)
```