# Operating system level security Android

Tags: android, security, operating-system

I have a requirement for trying to develop an alternative to the current pin password security system on the android operating system.  The main goal will be to try and replace the current password system with an alternative that uses one of the hardware features on the device.  Is this possible as a third party?  Or, would you need to go to the specific head set manufacturer to get the ability to circumvent  or change the current security system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is no API which is specifically designed to replace/be a pluging to a lock screen on Android.

However, people found several clever way of implementing it:

- Replace home screen
- Showing activity on top of lock screen

Take a look at these questions:

[Where can I find examples or tutorials about creating a custom android lockscreen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983143/where-can-i-find-examples-or-tutorials-about-creating-a-custom-android-lockscree)

[Customizing Android Lock Screen functionality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948617/customizing-android-lock-screen-functionality)